# Setting Accessible Role of controls in WPF Form

Tags: .net, wpf

I want controls on WPF Form to be available in a class so that I can set their values through a class. In Windows Forms, I used to open the designer file and set the property to Public. How to make a control property to Public in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [x:FieldModifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx) like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" x:FieldModifier="public">
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood do you want include on WPF form WinForms control? If yes you should look at the article [Host Win forms in WPF](http://www.nayyeri.net/host-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf)